# UWP SwapChainPanel Contents Blurry/Scaled

Tags: c#, uwp, directx, opengl-es-2.0, skiasharp

I am using [skia](http://skia.org/) to do drawing on a `SwapChainPanel` (via ANGLE), and all is going well. However, the one issue that I am having is that the content is being scaled on high DPI screens.

I have a hi-res (x2) and a normal (x1) screen on my machine here. The contents of the panel look great on the 1x display, but when I drag it over, the window resizes and scales the contents. How do I tell the panel not to scale the contents, but to rather let me adjust my side?

My current solution is to create my renderbuffer at the desired scale (eg: `panel.Width * 2`) and then use the `RenderTransform` property and set the `ScaleTransform` (eg: `0.5`).

The content now appears smooth and crisp, but now the layout is affected. Since the render transform has "resized" the panel.

What is the correct way to do this?

**EDIT**

This is what I am doing to create the buffer:

https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/blob/master/source/SkiaSharp.Views/SkiaSharp.Views.UWP/AngleSwapChainPanel.cs#L199-L285

Answer (score 2):

You essentially have to set scale on DXGISwapChain to be inverse of swap chain panel composition scale using [IDXGISwapChain2.SetMatrixTransform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn268312(v=vs.85).aspx) method:

```
SwapChainPanel panel = ...;
IDXGISwapChain2 swapChain = ...;

DXGI_MATRIX_3X2_F scale;
inverseScale._11 = 1.0f / swapChainPanel.CompositionScaleX;
inverseScale._22 = 1.0f / swapChainPanel.CompositionScaleY;
var hr = swapChain.SetMatrixTransform(ref scale);
if (hr < 0)
    Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
```

I don't know exactly how to obtain the swapchain object reference through the library you're using, though.